# histogram went in to infinite loop

Tags: c, structure, histogram

Hi I have this code here

```
int calMode(RECORD list[], int count)
{
    int tempMode = 1;
    int i = 1, j, k;
    int current = 0;

  while ( i <= count)
  {
       k = 1;
       if (list[current].score == list[current + i].score)
       {
          k++;
          i++;
       }
       printf("%d:", list[current].score);
       for(j = 0; j <= k ; j++)
       {
            printf("*");
       }
       printf("\n");
       current = current + k;
           i++;
  } 
   return tempMode;
}
```

I thought the logic of the code is ok, why is it going into an infinite loop ?

can anyone suggest a way to fix this code? and the list of data is assume to be sorted before going into the function calMode, I think there is a problem at the for loop

I edited the code know my out put is

```
60
66
71
71
72
75
79
82
82
82
91
size is: 12
73.50
60:**
66:*
71:*
71:*
72:*
75:*
79:*
82:*
82:*
82:*
91:*
```

The output is wrong but it is no longer in infinite loop

Comment: What's the goal of your edit. In this case, the loop will be infinite anyway still you re-initialise `i` each time ...

Comment: can you suggest another way of writing this code, I'm getting a bit stuck on the logic of the code

Comment: Actually, i don't really now what your code is supposed to do

Comment: it only suppose to print out a histogram which list of scores and their number of occurrences which represent as asterisk, so for example if we have 60 and 60 then the code will output 60: **

Comment: I think the easiest way to do it is to do two loops. The first one iterates on list and creates another one that will contains the count of each value.
Then second loop iterates on the previously created list to display the histogram.

Comment: well but you still have to check to see if some value are the same to the other values or not which would another if statement

Comment: is it normal that `i` starts at value `1`, not at `0` ?

Comment: ussually it is not normal to do that, but I have edit the code again, It got a better result but still not right yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIX E.g.

```
int calMode(RECORD list[], int count){
    int tempMode = 1;
    int i, k;
    int current = 0;

    while (current < count){
        printf("%d:", list[current].score);
        for(k=0; (i=current + k) < count ; ++k){
            if(list[current].score == list[i].score)
                printf("*");
            else 
                break;
        }
        printf("\n");
        current = current + k;
    } 
   return tempMode;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 if (list[current].score == list[i].score)
 {
     k++;
     i++;
 }
```

If this test is wrong, `i` will never be incremented and here is the infinite loop.

Comment: wait if that test is wrong then the program will get out of the if statement and proceed to print out the current index

Comment: @user1763658 Yes, but so what? It still *won't increment `i`* and thus the loop will not move forward, so the next iteration will be exactly the same, forever. If this happens on the first iteration when `k = 0`, then you're stuck.

Comment: Yes. That's right. Then the for loop will be processed, `current` will be incremented by `k`. But if the `if` test is skipped since the first iteration, `k` will never be incremented either.

Comment: yes you are right i have edited the code, now i should be increment

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, if the scores of 0 th elemennt and 1st element are not equal, it will end up in infinite loop. I think some increment condition should be outside if statement too. [I dont know your logic, this is just a guess]